# Easy way to concatenate two byte arrays in kotlin?

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin

What is the easiest way to concatenate two byte arrays in Kotlin?

Consider,

```
val x = ByteArray(a);
val y = ByteArray(b);
```

Help me to concatenate two byte arrays `x,y` and store it in another `ByteArray`?

Comment: How about x + y ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is a operator function `plus` for `ByteArray` (and all other arrays)

```
operator fun ByteArray.plus(elements: ByteArray): ByteArray

Returns an array containing all elements of the original array and then all elements of the given elements array.
```

so, you can simply use this function as an operator:

```
val z ByteArray = x + y
```

there are also overloaded editions:

```
operator fun ByteArray.plus(element: Byte): ByteArray


operator fun ByteArray.plus(elements: Collection<Byte>): ByteArray
```

Please refer this document for details:
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/plus.html

BTW, there are many many overloaded editions of this function,

e.g, you can plus a (`Iterable<T>`, `Collection<T>`, or `Array<T>`) and another (`Iterable<T>`, `Collection<T>`, `Array<T>`, or `Sequence<T>`), then get a `List<T>`,

or you can plus a `Set<T>` and another (`Array<out T>`, `Iterable<T>`, or `Sequence<T>`), then get a `Set<T>`

all these overloaded edition are operator functions, which means you can use it like `listA + arrayB`

the `a + b` operator will invoke operator function `a.plus(b)`

Please refer this document for details:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html

Comment: It's not concatenate operation. It's sum of byte arrays. It should not be  marked as best answer.

Comment: @Nihilus13 What's the difference?

Answer (score 4):

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val x = ByteArray(a);
    val y = ByteArray(b);

    val xLen = x.size
    val yLen = y.size
    val result = ByteArray(xLen + yLen)

    System.arraycopy(x, 0, result, 0, xLen)
    System.arraycopy(y, 0, result, xLen, yLen)

    // so now result is array that concatenate two byte arrays x,y
}
```

hope this helps